# Move view with finger use ViewFlipper

Tags: android, viewflipper

Can we move a view that defined in ViewFlipper with finger,**like we move view that define in
Gallery**,in other word,when we press view container, then move,we can see ***both view A,and B*** until press up. I think the key is the Override method onScroll().but it looks a little complex.or other we can change the view's switching style that in ViewFlipper **only through anim?**

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need a ViewPager.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want, then you need to use ViewPager, not ViewFlipper.

Comment: Thank you a lot,I just want make sure ViewFliper can't do that.

Comment: ViewFlipper cannot do it out of the box, but you can always extend it, if you need to.

Comment: I agree,Nothing is impossible,but we always needs the most efficient choice.:)

Comment: `ViewFlipper extends ViewAnimator` may be the Animation is the core value of ViewFlipper. Thank's again Raunak,Aleks G.